Retrieving ID when Multiple renderDataTable are active in Shiny App
I am trying to delete the values based on ID of the selected row in the datatable. My app has many datatable and when I use it always displays NULL. How can I retrieve the id/species (iris data) when I have selected a row in the datatable. Below is a sample example
Tried to store the values as reactive reactive. Searched across available resources.
Sample Code
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("table1"),
    dataTableOutput("table2"),
    textOutput("text1"),
    textOutput("text2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris)
    })
    
    output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(mtcars)
    })  
    output$text1 <- renderText({
      if(length(input$table_rows_selected) > 0){
        data <-  input$table_rows_selected
        data}
      else{print("NULL")}
    })
    output$text2 <- renderText({
      if(length(input$table_rows_selected) > 0){
        data <-  input$table_rows_selected
        data}
      else{print("NULL")}
    })
    
  }
)


You need use the ID of the table and then add _rows_selected i.e. input$table1_rows_selected
